# Простой последовательный консольный ввод в java

Tags: java

Доброго всем времени суток господа, второй раз за сегодня. (Первые шаги в Java)

```
// интел идея 12.1.4
// есть вот такой код
    char inChar1;
    out.println("Inp1: ");
    inChar1 = (char) in.read();
    out.print("Out: "+inChar1);
```

Вводим '1', получаем '1'. Вводим 'q', получаем 'q'. Все пашет.

```
// переделал:
    char inChar1;
    char inChar2;
    char inChar3;
    out.println("Inp1: ");
    inChar1 = (char) in.read();
    out.println("Inp2: ");
    inChar2 = (char) in.read();
    out.println("Inp3: ");
    inChar3 = (char) in.read();
    out.print("Out: "+inChar1+"/"+inChar2+"/"+inChar3);
```

Ну можно пережить отсутствия кирилицы, но после ввода одного символа, ввожу второй и сразу выдается результат (т.е. должен быть ввод 3х символов). Кроме того по многочисленным примерам в инете максимум что и нашел что ввод символа, а не слова.

Вопрос: Как организовать ввод 3х строк? Ввел первую строку, энтер, вторую, энтер, третью, энтер -> вижу что ввел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: эм.. это единственное решение? оч. интересует не подключение отдельных классов, а что то очень простое, что исправляет текущие неточности в моем коде

Comment: Всегда используйте Scanner для чтения из консоли, это и есть очень простое решение.